# Fourier transform of subgroups of $(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})^*$

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, finite-groups, fourier-transform

Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity, and for each function $f : \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{C}$ define its Fourier transform $\widehat{f} : \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z} \to \mathbf{C}$ by
$$\widehat{f}(a) = \sum_{x \in \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}} f(x) \zeta^{ax} .$$
Further, for any $A \subseteq \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$ put $\widehat{A}(a) = \widehat{\mathbf{1}_A}(a)$, where $\mathbf{1}_A$ is the indicator function of $A$.

If $G$ is a subgroup of $(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})^*$, what can we say about the dimension of the $\mathbf{Q}$-vector space spanned by $\{\widehat{G}(a) : a \in \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}\}$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is $\widehat{A}(a) = {\bf 1}_A(a)$, or should it be $\widehat{{\bf 1}_A}(a)$?

Comment: @MattYoung the second one, I have forgot a hat. Thanks!

Comment: Is this homework? (Hint: use Galois theory)

Comment: @UriBader It is not homework, but I would not be surprised if it turned out to be easy. What I know from Galois theory is that the $\widehat{G}(a)$'s are all algebraic coniugated BUT when $a$ runs over $(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})^*$, because of the identification of this last group with the Galois group of $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta)$ over $\mathbf{Q}$. However, I do not see how this could help...

Comment: Sercej, sorry that I had to ask. It is just that your question fits so nicely the theory, so I had to verify this. I answered it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension is $\phi(n)/|G|$.

Denote the $\mathbb{Q}$-span of $\{\hat{G}(a)\mid a\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\}$ in $\mathbb{C}$ by $V$.
Observe that $V<\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, which is a Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ with Galois group $\Gamma\simeq (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^*$.
Identifying $G$ with a subgroup of $\Gamma$, I claim that $V$ is the space of $G$-invariants, which leads to the above expression by Galois' theorem.

Observe that $v\mapsto \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{x\in G} x(v)$ is a projection of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ on $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)^G$, hence also the image of the operator $P(v)=\sum_{x\in G} x(v)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)^G$. We therefore need to show that $P(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta))=V$. Since $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is spanned by $\{\zeta^a\}$, it is enough to show that the span of $\{P(\zeta^a)\}$ is $V$.
This indeed holds since, under our identification $x(\zeta)=\zeta^x$, we have 
$$ P(\zeta^a)=\sum_{x\in G}x(\zeta^{a}) =\sum_{x\in G}\zeta^{ax} =\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}}\mathbf{1}_G(x)\zeta^{ax}  =\hat{G}(a). $$

Comment: Hence when $n$ is prime the $\widehat{G}(a)$'s are linearly independent over $\mathbf{Q}$, since they are exactly $\phi(n) / |G|$. But for composite $n$ this is false. I guess that it should not be easy to extract a linearly independent subset from $\{\widehat{G}(a) : a \in \mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}\}$ without further information.

Comment: @sercej If you are looking for a basis for $V$, note that $\zeta^a$, $a=0,\ldots,\phi(n)-1$ form a basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, hence $\hat{G}(a)=P(\zeta^a)$ form a basis of $V$ (with repetition).

Comment: I would like a basis of $V$ without repetitions: For example, I checked that in general $\widehat{G}(a)$ with $a$ running on a set of representatives of the cosets of $G$ in $(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})^*$ is NOT a basis (althought it has $\phi(n) / |G|$ elements.

Comment: I am sure that with some thought you will handle this problem.